# How to achieve ssh passwordless login in AWS Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm going to setup a Hadoop cluster using AWS CloudFormation. Some Hadoop helper scripts need to establish passwordless ssh connection from master node to slave nodes(using file 'etc/hadoop/slaves').
Generally, this could be achieve by generating ssh key pair and append master node's public key into slave node ~/.ssh/authorized_keys. But how to do that using AWS CloudFormation template?

Answer (score 0):

Cloudformation does not support generating keypairs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-iam-accesskey.html

What I would do is use an S3 bucket that contains the private/public keys and use those on startup. The private would go to ~/.ssh/stack.pem for example and the public into ~/.ssh/authorized_keys.

Another option is to use a string parameter to the CF stack for 'public' and 'private' keys if you do not wish to have them stored elsewhere.

You can be creative here, but there is not a way to create and pass around a keypair.

Remember that CF is 'infrastructure as code' so you may even write a script that generates a keypair, generates a temporary S3 bucket, uploads the keyfiles there, creates the CF template which goes to the temporary s3 bucket (parameter), puts them where they need to be on each instance, and then the script can clean up (delete bucket + keys).

Comment: Passing the keys in as a parameter has caused issues for myself and quite a few other people https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=165630.
Seems that aws strips the line ending which causes the key not to work. 
The other option of using an s3 bucket requires creating an IAM role with permission to read from private s3 buckets. This IAM role cannot be cleaned up automatically as part of the template so must be done manually. 
If anyone has any other solutions to this problem I would be very thankful.